Probability of a Markov Chain value conditional on an observation of the next step
Let $X=(X_i)_{i \ge 1}$ be a Markov chain and $Y=(Y_i)_{i \ge 1}$ be such that $Y_i=\phi(X_i)$ for an arbitrary function $\phi$.
In attempting to derive a recurrence relation for the expectations $\mathbb{E}[X_t|\{Y_s=y_s\}_{s\le t}]$, my lecturer claims:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X_t|\{Y_s=y_s\}_{s\le t}\right] = \sum_{x'}{\mathbb{E}[X_t|X_{t-1}=x',\{Y_s=y_s\}_{s\le t}]}\mathbb{P}\left(X_{t-1}=x'|\{Y_s=y_s\}_{s\le t-1}\right)$$
You will note the "$s\le t-1$" on that final probability  - which is what I'm struggling to understand. Does knowledge of $Y_t$ not influence our beliefs about $X_{t-1}$? For example, this would restrict us to values of $X_{t-1}$ that can in one step lead to preimages of $Y_t$, no?
For completeness, note that this is in a proof of the Wonham Filter for discrete Markov chains.

I've figured this out but will leave up for anyone else confused. Yes, an observation of the next state affects our beliefs about the current state - but this information is already encoded in the observation $Y_{t-1}$ of the current state. Conditioning on both yields no more than conditioning on just $Y_{t-1}$.

Does that mean $Y_t$ should be a function of $X_{t-1}$ instead of $X_t$ in the question?

This is a standard HMM so no, $Y_t$ is a function of its hidden counterpart $X_t$ - though note this includes a dependency on $X_{t-1}$ via the underlying Markov chain.
